# Filling Column based on lag column value - python

Tags: python, string, count, lag

I have a data table:

| Team | vpos | hpos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| home |  |  |
| away |  |  |
| away |  |  |
| away |  |  |
| home |  |  |
| home |  |  |
| away |  |  |

I would like to add a number the number 1 in vpos or hpos where the team switches to signify a change in position.  I figured I would use some type of lag but I do not know how to do that in python.  I would like the final table to look like this:

| Team | vpos | hpos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| home |  | 1 |
| away | 1 |  |
| away |  |  |
| away |  |  |
| home |  | 1 |
| home |  |  |
| away | 1 |  |

Any direction would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data table is a Pandas dataframe `df` then you could try:

```py
m = df["Team"].shift() != df["Team"]
df.loc[m & df["Team"].eq("away"), "vpos"] = 1
df.loc[m & df["Team"].eq("home"), "hpos"] = 1
```

Result for `df`

```
   Team
0  home
1  away
2  away
3  away
4  home
5  home
6  away
```

is

```
   Team  vpos  hpos
0  home   NaN   1.0
1  away   1.0   NaN
2  away   NaN   NaN
3  away   NaN   NaN
4  home   NaN   1.0
5  home   NaN   NaN
6  away   1.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you use Pandas dataframe:

```py
tmp = (df["Team"] != df["Team"].shift()).cumsum()

df["vpos"] = df.groupby(tmp)["Team"].transform(
    lambda x: [1] + [np.nan] * (len(x) - 1) if x.iat[0] != "home" else np.nan
)

df["hpos"] = df.groupby(tmp)["Team"].transform(
    lambda x: [1] + [np.nan] * (len(x) - 1) if x.iat[0] == "home" else np.nan
)

df = df.fillna("")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Team vpos hpos
0  home       1.0
1  away  1.0     
2  away          
3  away          
4  home       1.0
5  home          
6  away  1.0
```